# Merge excel sheets in java by contents of a specific column

Tags: java, excel

I have to merge two excel files using a column value similar in both.

```
For example

excel 1                                    excel2
1   ab                                      1  rat cat
2   cd                                      2  mat sat
3   ef                                      3  fat vat

should be merged as
1   ab rat cat
2   cd mat sat
3   ef fat vat
```

I have to do it in java..

please suggest how to move further... If any code is available for the same it would be helpful..

regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/ to read and write Excel files in Java. The rest shouldn't be more than a few loops, maybe a HashMap to speed it up...